# API support for Instagram Direct

Tags: api, instagram

Instagram recently announced support for direct messages to users: http://blog.instagram.com/post/69789416311/instagram-direct.

It doesn't look like accessing received direct messages for an authenticated user is possible through the Instagram API. If that's the case, are there plans to support such a feature? If not, can someone describe which endpoint I have to use to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no Instagram API for direct share at the moment. The URLs they use from the app for the direct share page are as follows, first for the list of shares:

```
https://instagram.com/api/v1/direct_share/inbox/
```

and second for the pending requests

```
https://instagram.com/api/v1/direct_share/pending/
```

Comment: Confused - those URLs are API endpoints, no? By "no API" do you mean "not supported in client libraries"?

Comment: @djechlin correct, they are undocumented and haven't been announced, therefore assumed to be unsupported

Comment: how can i use this i want to use this api into ios when i am requesting url with accesstoken i m getting required login. i m requesting url on browser