# How to use Instagram Direct message Api

Tags: android, instagram-api

I am looking for Instagram Direct message API, I tried some private API libraries but I couldn't find any direct message API
How I can use Instagram Direct message API correctly?

I had a look at other posts, but they did not solved my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use instagram direct api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676432/how-to-use-instagram-direct-api)

Comment: it did not work to me  @KrishnaSony

Answer (score 1):

There is no Instagram API for direct messages, I guess there won't be any. You may be able to use the Instagram node.js Private API library

I have to warn you though, that I did try to use the PHP library and Instagram didn't
If you are able to use node.js, it seems that Thread.configureText can be used for sending direct messages on the node.js library.

https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api

Alternatively, I would suggest using a headless web scraper like Selenium or Cypress

Comment: it did not work to me

Comment: @KavehGarshasp Instagram deprecated most of the API