# How can I capture Direct Message via Instagram API?

Tags: instagram

I searched the api instagram if there is any method to return the direct messages, and found nothing. Can you tell if there is something, or if it is not possible? Instagram does not offer? Or I can do programmatically?
I need capture direct message, is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API support for Instagram Direct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609028/api-support-for-instagram-direct)

Comment: I made scripts to read and send Instagram direct messages from a web browser: https://gist.github.com/baptx/1e61eef2e1ec200b6e7b32409f79c07f https://gist.github.com/baptx/99f3cb6373d4a8cf869c25f0549b0c5c

Answer (score 5):

There is no Instagram API for direct messages, and since it's been almost 4 years now, I guess there won't be any. You may be able to use the [Instagram node.js Private API](https://github.com/huttarichard/instagram-private-api) library or the <s>Instagram PHP Private API library</s>.

I have to warn you though, that I did try to use the PHP library and Instagram didn't allow sending of direct messages, no matter how much hacking I tried to make it work. But maybe this was just me...

If you are able to use node.js, it seems that Thread.configureText can be used for sending direct messages on the node.js library.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)  PHP library can sen direct messages through Instagram Private API, and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
string status_DM = string.Empty;
string Url_DirectMessage = "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/direct_v2/threads/broadcast/text/";
string guid = obj_InstaUser.guid;
string userID = string.Empty;  // put user id to whom you want to send message

string responce = obj_new.getHtmlfromUrl(new Uri("https://www.instagram.com/" + username));

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
{
    userID = Utils.getBetween(responce, "profilePage_", "}").Replace(" ","").Replace("\"","");
}
try
{
    string postData = "recipient_users=%5B%5B%22" + userID + "%22%5D%5D&client_context=%22" + guid + "%22&text=" + text + "&thread_ids=%5B%220%22%5D";
    try
    {
        string  Finalresult = obj_InstaUser.globusHttpHelperMobile.postFormDataMobileLogin_Directmessage(new Uri(Url_DirectMessage), postData);

        status_DM = "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        status_DM = "Fail";
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Where I will get globusHttpHelperMobile.postFormDataMobileLogin_Directmessage ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [instagram-messager-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram) now.
the page you intended to receive its DMs must have 1k-100k followers.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 16, 2021 you can send and receive IG messages through the official API.

Here is a quote from the official "FACEBOOK for developers" website:
"All Instagram business accounts can connect to Messenger API for Instagram as of August 16, 2021." ([Instagram Messaging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/))

Comment: is there any good, step by step document or tutorial? I can't understand the official document

Comment: I'm not aware of such document, but I guess you can try asking ChatGPT or Gemini to provide you with step by step instructions.

Answer (score -4):

Use Instagram private API. Through this you are able to send Direct message.
I did in C# and that worked perfectly. (Direct message and upload post as well.)

Comment: Can you provide a github link to the c# project?

Comment: same here please! @jolta